# TypeScript each() as an Arrow function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, each, arrow-functions

I have the following TypeScript function:

```
$.each($("[data-static-map-image]"), function () {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("mapImageUrl"));
});
```

I would like to convert this into an Arrow function. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to make it work with the each loop. Can someone give me a hint?

P.S. I ask for your indulgence as I am still in the beginning of the learning phase.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery in 2022?

Comment: It is unfortunately given within the scope of the project I am involved in. So I have to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery documentation on [jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) explains that the callback gets arguments:

> **callback**
> Type: Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value )
> The function that will be executed on every value.

So if you really want to stick with jQuery, then make use of the arguments passed to the callback function:

```
$.each($("[data-static-map-image]"), (i, elem) => {
    $(elem).attr("src", $(elem).data("mapImageUrl"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain JavaScript (and TypeScript too)

Use `querySelectorAll` to get all elements matching your selector and then use the `Array#forEach` function:

```js
const allElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-static-map-image]'))

allElements.forEach(element => {
  const url = element.getAttribute('data-mapImageUrl')
  element.setAttribute('src', url)
})
```

The main reason you cannot use an arrow function in your context is because `this` refers to the outer scope as opposed when using anonymous functions which have their own `this` which jQuery is going to bind to each of the elements

Comment: There is no need to call `Array.from`.

Comment: True. But I find it very convenient as `NodeList` is missing some of the `Array` functional predicates such as `filter`

Comment: In that case, you don't need `forEach`, and can use the callback argument of `Array.from`.

Comment: That'd be mapping each of the elements into a new Array in case we still store stuff into a variable and resulting an array of `undefined` if we forget to return the element